# One column bibliography in two column article

Tags: bibliographies, revtex

I couldn't find the answer, so I'm asking. I'm writing a two column article, in the first column on the last page I would like to have the article text and bibliography in the second column (whole in one column). Now bibliography is added automatically in two columns at the end. I'm using [**revtex 4.1**](https://ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1) and not using bibtex.

Do you have any suggestions?

Edit

Ok, I try with an example. This is what I have:

```
\documentclass[aps,reprint,twocolumn,groupedaddress,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\title{Just an example}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-4]

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{1} J.~Bond, S.~Connery.
\textit{Goldfinger.}
Eon Productions, {\bf 106}, 106 (1964).

\bibitem{2} J.~Bond, S.~Connery.
\textit{Goldfinger.}
Eon Productions, {\bf 106}, 106 (1964).

\bibitem{3} J.~Bond, S.~Connery.
\textit{Goldfinger.}
Eon Productions, {\bf 106}, 106 (1964).

\bibitem{4} J.~Bond, S.~Connery.
\textit{Goldfinger.}
Eon Productions, {\bf 106}, 106 (1964).

\bibitem{5} J.~Bond, S.~Connery.
\textit{Goldfinger.}
Eon Productions, {\bf 106}, 106 (1964).

\bibitem{6} J.~Bond, S.~Connery.
\textit{Goldfinger.}
Eon Productions, {\bf 106}, 106 (1964).

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

And what I would like to have according to this example to 'move' whole bibliography to the right and keep the text in the left column.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: try add `\onecolumngrid` just befor `\begin{thebibliography}{99}`

Comment: What it does is enlarging the width of bibliography to whole page if I'm right. I would like to keep the two columns format.

Comment: Too late at night here to try, but the documentation of revtex suggest that the `nobalancelastpage` option might be what you are looking for.

Comment: So I tried it:   `\documentclass[aps,reprint,twocolumn,groupedaddress,amsmath,amssymb, nobalancelastpage]{revtex4-1} ` and it unbalances the bibliography indeed but keeps it organized in two columns. I think I will leave as it is, balanced bibliography in two columns. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and all I did was putting bibliography command inside the
`\onecolumn{}` command.

```
\onecolumn{
    \bibliographystyle{apalike}
    \bibliography{physics.bib}}
```